# Making visual assist document all methods in a certain class \ page

Tags: visual-studio, visual-assist

Is it possible to build a script to force VAx to document all methods \ functions of a certain class?
I find it quite annoying to manually document each new function i write. i tried customizing visual assist's shortcuts using the following key: `VAssistX.RefactorDocumentMethod` but it neither solved any of my laziness issues.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no command in Visual Assist to document all methods of a class at once, but you can use the combination of VAssistX.RefactorDocumentMethod and VAssistX.ScopeNext to document one method and place you at the position to document the next. Repeat for each method.

20 methods should take 40 less one commands to document.